# When using google-api-java-client , I can't get to parse attributes of node elements. Can anyone tell me how to use it?

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api, google-api-java-client

On google-api-java-client exists an annotation @Key that it's used for parsing nodes on an XML. I received an answer from analytics service that contains several nodes that start with "dxp:property ". I only need the node that has the attribute name="ga:accountName" for getting the value of another attribute on the same node. But, I don't know if it exists an implementation on the library that google provided for parsing attributes, and I can't find any information on the documentation.

Does someone knows something about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Founded a way to do this! First, make a List of ProfileItems as an attribute of a class such as:

```
public class Profile {

    @Key("dxp:property")
    public List<ProfileItem> profiles;

}
```

Where ProfileItem is defined as:

```
public class ProfileItem {

    @Key("@name")
    public String name;

    @Key("@value")
    public String value;

}
```

The @ in the String of the Key annotation marks that *name* and *value* are attributes at the node dxp:property.

With this, now I can look for the name attribute that I want, that is ga:accountName.

See you!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing with the Google Calendar in regard to the "startTime" and "endTime" of a calendars event.  Could you take a look at my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298235/get-google-calendar-events-start-and-end-times-with-google-java-api-client-in-and and tell me what I'm doing wrong?