# Set Google Calendar query parameters with google-java-api-client in Android

Tags: java, android, google-api-java-client

I'm building a URL to gain access to a users Google calendar with the google-javi-api as such:

```
CalendarUrl url = CalendarUrl.forEventFeed("accountName", "private", "full");
```

which returns me this url:

```
"https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/user@gmail.com/private/full?prettyprint=true"
```

I would like to set parameters to this URL with startMin and startMax parameters so the URL would eventually look like this:

```
"https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full?start-min=2011-06-00T00:00:00&start-max=2011-06-24T23:59:59"
```

All of my attempts at this have failed, and after logging the URL that is being returned, I find that the "?" is being replaced by "%3F" and ampersands are being replaced by "&"

The incorrect url that is bring returned is:

```
"https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full%3Fstart-min=2011-06-00T00:00:00&amp;start-max=2011-06-24T23:59:59"
```

I'm pretty sure the reason my result set is null is because of those character replacements.  How do I append the original URL with the new parameters?

**If you're wondering how I'm building this url, I'm using the [CalendarURL](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/calendar/android/model/CalendarUrl.java?repo=samples) class from this [sample Android implementation of Google Calendar](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/?repo=samples).

**EDIT**

More specifically, in the [CalendarURL](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/calendar/android/model/CalendarUrl.java?repo=samples) class, I can add parts to the "path" of the URL, but I can't find a way to include a query parameter.  Does this API not include a way to specify a parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to create a URL using google-java-client-api is to extend the GoogleUrl object. (I'm using Google Latitude here as a sample. I create a GoogleUrl object, and later on you'll see how it gets used).

**The Google URL object**

- You construct a URL object extending GoogleUrl
- You annotate the parameters you would like to customize on the URL using the @Key annotation
- You provide a constructor that takes on the root url.
- You add parts to the context using the pathParts.add method

A sample URL object looks like this:

```
public final class LatitudeUrl extends GoogleUrl {

  @Key
  public String granularity;

  @Key("min-time")
  public String minTime;

  @Key("max-time")
  public String maxTime;

  @Key("max-results")
  public String maxResults;

  /** Constructs a new Latitude URL from the given encoded URI. */
  public LatitudeUrl(String encodedUrl) {
    super(encodedUrl);
  }

  private static LatitudeUrl root() {
    return new LatitudeUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/latitude/v1");
  }

  public static LatitudeUrl forCurrentLocation() {
    LatitudeUrl result = root();
    result.pathParts.add("currentLocation");
    return result;
  }

  public static LatitudeUrl forLocation() {
    LatitudeUrl result = root();
    result.pathParts.add("location");
    return result;
  }

  public static LatitudeUrl forLocation(Long timestampMs) {
    LatitudeUrl result = forLocation();
    result.pathParts.add(timestampMs.toString());
    return result;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

You use this object to construct the URL, just fill in your parameters (the @Key annotated fields), and execute the build() method to get a string representation of it :

```
    LatitudeUrl latitudeUrl = LatitudeUrl.forLocation();
    latitudeUrl.maxResults="20";
    latitudeUrl.minTime="123";
    latitudeUrl.minTime="456";

    System.out.println(latitudeUrl.build());
```

**Output :**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/latitude/v1/location?max-results=20&min-time=456
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Is the usage that I posted in my answer above an incorrect way of getting a URL with parameters?  Your way looks like a great way to get this done and I have no doubt that it works, but what is the difference between your way and mine?  The only reason why I ask is because I learn best when seeing the difference.

Comment: See my comment on your answer :) Using the @Key annotation you have a generic way of declaring your URL (including  the parameters). The same @Key attribute can be used to retrieve data from the responses. It makes your code easier to read because its strongly typed.The  google-api-java-client way of working is using the @Key annotation.

Comment: Also, google-api-java-client will be releasing a lot of generated client libraries, including these Url objects. So as a developer, you start using the Url objects (you don't have to write them yourself anymore), and by looking at their fields, you immediately get an idea on how the interface (= the API = the url + parameters) looks like to interact with the API.

Comment: sorry to do this again....but.....another question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403293/google-api-java-client-for-google-calendar-on-android-infinite-loop - ;-)...

Answer (score 1):

After some serious digging I found out how to include query parameters using the google-java-api.

To add any of these [Query Parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html#Parameters) to a URL, do the following:

After building the basic CalendarUrl, call .put("Key", "Value") to add query parameters.  For example:

```
CalendarUrl eventFeedUrl = CalendarUrl.forEventFeed("user@gmail.com", "private", "full");

  eventFeedUrl.put("start-min", "2011-06-01T00:00:00");
  eventFeedUrl.put("start-max", "2011-06-22T00:00:00");
```

I just happened to stumble across a thread buried in the midst of a junk-load of unfiltered "issues" at the project home at Google.  There is plenty of documentation for using the gData api, but there is NOTHING for the google-java-api.  It took me almost 2 days to find this simple method call.  Very frustrating.  I hope whoever reads this didn't go through what I went through to find out how to accomplish this simple, yet crucial task.  It should be better documented.

Comment: The GoogleUrl objects in google-api-java-client are actually implemented as Maps, explaining why you can add parameters using put(key,value). However, this is fairly low-level stuff, and as a developer you shouldn't see it as a map. By annotation certain fields (representing parameters) with the @Key attribute, you accomplish the same thing. The code is much clearer that way (see my answer for an example)